# Capture traffic on web server

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-services, network-traffic

I have a web server that is accepting web service calls on port 8081 - I want to see the packets coming through. I tried using fiddler, but it doesn't see anything. I don't have access to the code, its precompiled. I was hoping to just install something on the server to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use wireshark on the server.

Then you can capture all traffic, and analyze it afterwords.

Comment: tried that.... the webservice calls aren't seen for whatever reason..

Comment: Then you might have a firewall issue, or something related.
If you could put the switchport the server is on in monitoring mode, and put up a computer with wireshark installed on that port, you can see if it is the server or something else that blocks.

Comment: I ran it directly ON the server, and it still doesn't see it...

Comment: Exactly. Check the units *before* the server to see where the packets get lost.

Comment: no, I know for a fact the server is sending the requests - there are no firewalls in place...

Comment: Now it gets confusing. Do you want to see the packets going **into** the server, or the packets **leaving** the server?

Comment: packets coming INTO the server, or packets leaving FROM the server..

Comment: Aight. Do you use any filters in wireshark? If you cannot see the **incoming** packets, there must be some firewall ahead of the server preventing them from coming in. For packets **leaving** the server, either the application does not work, or you use a wrong filter in wireshark.